# in scala how can i reflection creates the underlying type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-reflect

Let's say I have the following:

`val int_string = "Int"`

I want to get a map. In the process of running the program, I need to infer its type from the data, and then create a map，like in spark dataframe

| key | count | key_radio | sample_radio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0.2857142857142857 | 0.5 |
| 3 | 2 | 0.2857142857142857 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 3 | 0.42857142857142855 | 0.5 |

I only know the key column is “int”，but how can I create the `Int` object? from the string “Int”

`Map[Int,Double] = ???`

Answer (score 1):

In `val int_string = "Int"` the string `"Int"` is a runtime thing.

In `val m: Map[Int,Double] = ???` the type `Int` is a compile-time thing.

[Runtime vs. Compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time)

You can't have `Int` at compile time (i.e. earlier) based on information at runtime (i.e. later).

You should provide more details how you're going to use `Map[Int,Double]`, why is `Map[Any,Double]` not enough etc.

Depending on your use case, `Map[Any,Double]` (or even `Map[Any,Any]`) could be enough or something else can be done or in rare cases, when `Int` is actually significant, one can use reflective toolbox (creating new compile time inside runtime)

```
tb.eval(tb.parse(s"val m: Map[$int_string,Double] = ???"))
```

[Scala - looping over case class names to use as type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69598705)

[Covariant case class mapping to its base class without a type parameter and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69556749)

[Invoke a template Scala function with a type stored as wild card classTag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69502964)

[test for membership in Scala type class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69487499) (2)

[Scala resolving Class/Type at runtime + type class constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69315834)

[scala get generic type by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68757112)

Comment: My main problem is how to create a case class through the types in the obtained string during code running

Comment: @user3167604 Why do you need a case class? How are you going to use it? Why `Map[Any,Double]` or `Map[Any,Any]` is not enough?